# How to Change Second `background-image` Without Having to Refer to the First?

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I'm trying to be able to change the `background-color`, behind a `background-image`, like this:

```js
document.getElementById("abc").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("abc").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
```

```css
#abc{
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 5px solid;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Click to see changes.</p>
<div id="abc">
  <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 3em; color: yellow;">Words</p> <!-- Ignore this line -->
</div>
```

But, I want to use a `linear-gradient`, and therefore have to put it in the same property as the image (`background-image`):

```js
document.getElementById("abc").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("abc").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png), linear-gradient(rgb(0, 100, 170), rgb(0, 70, 119))";
});
```

```css
#abc{
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 5px solid;
  background-image: url(https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png), linear-gradient(rgb(170, 40, 0), rgb(119, 10, 0));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Click to see changes.</p>
<div id="abc">
  <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 3em; color: yellow;">Words</p> <!-- Ignore this line -->
</div>
```

And when I do it that way, in order to change the background, I have to put `background-image: url(image.png), linear-gradient(newColor, newColor);`; I have to reference the first one again, in order to reference and change the second one.  Is there a way (with CSS) that I can not have to refer to the first one, but only refer to the second one to change it? e.g. `background-image: auto, linear-gradient(newColor, newColor);`.

Please let me know if anything was unclear.

Comment: why you need a linear gradient here?

Comment:  Because I would like a gradient, and not just a plain color. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use var() CSS and setProperty to set a value

```js
document.getElementById("abc").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("abc").style.setProperty('--bg','linear-gradient(rgb(0, 100, 170), rgb(0, 70, 119))');
});
```

```css
#abc{
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 5px solid;
  background-image: url(https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png), var(--bg,linear-gradient(rgb(170, 40, 0), rgb(119, 10, 0)));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Click to see changes.</p>
<div id="abc">
  <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 3em; color: yellow;">Words</p> <!-- Ignore this line -->
</div>
```

Ressources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var

---

edit: **Option without JavaScript**, but it will require to edit the html (attribute tabindex ) or add extra elements (alike hamburgers menu method)

```css
#abc,#def {
  width: 290px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 5px solid;
  background-image: url(https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png), var(--bg, linear-gradient(rgb(170, 40, 0), rgb(119, 10, 0)));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  display:grid
}

#abc:focus {
  --bg: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 100, 170), rgb(0, 70, 119));
}

/* input and label option */
#def{
position:relative;
}
[for="bg"]{position:absolute;inset:0 0 0 0;}
#bg{position:absolute;margin-inline-start:-100vw;}
#bg:checked~#def { --bg: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 100, 170), rgb(0, 70, 119));}
```

```html
<p>Click to see changes, via tabindex + :focus.</p>
<div id="abc" tabindex=0>
  <p style="margin:auto; color: yellow;">Words</p><!-- Ignore this line -->
</div>


<p>Click to see changes. via :checked input and a label</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="bg">
<div id="def">
<label for="bg"></label>
  <p style="margin:auto; color: yellow;">Words</p><!-- Ignore this line -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I meant to clarify strictly asking if there was a CSS method (whether like the example I gave at the end, or at least close to it). I appreciate your time though, I will change the OP.

Comment: @RobertBradley i added 2 CSS method, but it will require to modify the HTML (see the last snippet in the answser with 2 working examples . CSS var() is still used to avoid rewrite the whole rule. No javascript required for those two :)